# PowerShell: Why is this while() statement looping for ever?

Tags: powershell, while-loop

Why is the following while statement looping for ever? I want to break out after the users has entered "yes" or "no". Everything else should keep him in the input loop.

```
while ($input -ne "yes" -or $input -ne "no") {
    $input = Read-Host "Ready to process? [yes|no]"

    switch ($input) {
        yes { 
            write-host "yes"    
        }

        no  { 
            write-host "no" 
        }

        default { 
            write-host "input not understood" 

        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's unpick the logic:

1) If the input is "yes" then it's not equal to "no".

2) If the input is "no" then it's not equal to "yes".

3) If it's neither "yes" nor "no" then it's not equal to "yes" or "no".

Therefore `while ($input -ne "yes" -or $input -ne "no") {` is always true. So it loops forever.

I think you mean

```
while ($input -ne "yes" -and $input -ne "no") {
```

Interestingly, what you have here can be expressed with De Morgan's laws. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 1):

Because you're asking to loop when `$input` is not "yes" OR is not "no".

Truth table for `or`:

```
 A    B       A -or B
 F    F   ->     F
 F    T   ->     T
 T    F   ->     T
 T    T   ->     T
```

Imagine input is "yes", **second** condition is `true` then loop will go on. Imagine now input is "no" then **first** condition is `true` and loop wil go on again. Imagine now input is "maybe": both conditions are true and loop will go on. One of your conditions is always satisfied so loop won't ever stop (lines from 2 to 4 of truth table). Moreover from boolean logic you know that `!a and !b` equals to `!(a or b)`.

```
 A    B        A or B    not A and not B    not (A or B)
 F    F   ->   F         T                  T
 F    T   ->   T         F                  F
 T    F   ->   T         F                  F
 T    T   ->   T         F                  F
```

Operator you need is `and`: loop must be executed if input is not "yes" neither "no":

```
while ($input -ne "yes" -and $input -ne "no") {
```

It means: *if input is not "yes" and if it's not "no" then ask again*.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my code, but I was also looking for an answer to this question - jrv from TechNet suggested this spiffy one-liner, which works perfectly for me:

```
while(($ans=Read-Host 'Do you want to prepare the text (y / n)') -notmatch '^Y$|^N$'){}
```

Since "While" does whatever's inside the braces, it's saying "when the input isn't Y or N, do nothing" (it just repeats the question endlessly - so no need for the default "input not understood").

Hope this helps!

Source:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e93e9740-ef6c-49ab-bb53-b40ddcbeb0f4/validate-input-from-readhost-using-trycatch?forum=winserverpowershell#54e5b845-3ce0-4a75-9201-65f30689b717][1]